# Get text response from BootBox prompt

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

I'm trying to retrieve the text entered in the bootbox.prompt. The prompt comes up fine but I get no value because it doesn't wait for the value to be entered.

The context of it's use: when a specific selection is made from a dropdown, a certain field value is required. I could popup a message saying its required and put the focus on that field, but I'd rather get the value from the popup and populate the field (ie this prompt).

//trigger

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ShipmentTypeID, ViewBag.ShipmentTypes as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", onchange = "checkShipmentType();" })
```

//trigger action checkShipmentType() includes

```
switch($("#ShipmentTypeID").val()){
case 'somevalue':     
    var responseVal = promptEntry("Please enter the Originating Order");
    $("#OriginatingOrder").val(responseVal);
    break;
}
```

//in jquery myLibrary ...

```
function promptEntry(message) {
    try {
        var prompt = bootbox.prompt({
            title: '<i class="far fa-keyboard"></i>  ' + (typeof message === "undefined" ? "Entry Required" : message),
            centerVertical: true,
            callback: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
        .find('.modal-header').css({ 'background-color': '#3db9bf', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'border-color': '#3db9bf', color: '#8a6d3b', 'font-size': '2em' });

    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get it to do what I wanted, even though I don't like how it works. The callback routine is what activates when something is entered or a button is pressed. I could not get it to return a value, so I did what I need to do inside the callback routine.

My goal was to populate a textbox value with the entered value. So I sent in the 'name' of the object and populated the $(obj).val() with the result.

```
promptEntry("Please enter the Originating Order", "#OriginatingOrder");

function promptEntry(message, obj) {
    try {
        var prompt = bootbox.prompt({
            title: '<i class="far fa-keyboard"></i>  ' + (typeof message ===  "undefined" ? "Entry Required" : message),
            centerVertical: true,
            callback: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                $(obj).val(result);
            }
        }
     })
        .find('.modal-header').css({ 'background-color': '#3db9bf', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'border-color': '#3db9bf', color: '#8a6d3b', 'font-size': '2em' });

} catch (err) {
    alert(err);
}
```

}